# Reading Contact List in Micromax Q50

Tags: java-me, contacts

I am using the following code to read Contact List in Micromax Device.
   But without any success.

```
try {
        PIM t_pim = PIM.getInstance();

        String[] namesOfContactLists = t_pim.listPIMLists(PIM.CONTACT_LIST);

        PIMList t_pimlist = t_pim.openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY, namesOfContactLists[0]);//namesOfContactLists[0] is the Phone List.

        Enumeration t_enumeration = t_pimlist.items();

        boolean isFormattedNameSupported = t_pimlist.isSupportedField(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME);

        while (t_enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {

            String t_contactName = "";

            Contact t_contact = (Contact) t_enumeration.nextElement();

            if (isFormattedNameSupported) {

                if (t_contact.countValues(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME) > 0) {

                    t_contactName = t_contact.getString(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME, 0);//Throws UnsupportedFieldException

                }

            }

        }
    } catch (PIMException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Other options like Contact.NAME, Contact.NAME_GIVEN, Contact.NAME_FAMILY, Contact.NAME_OTHER, Contact.NAME_PREFIX, Contact.NAME_SUFFIX, Contact.NICKNAME also throw the same UnsupportedFieldException.

This code works fine on Nokia and Sony Ericsson devices. But fails on Micromax.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "without any success", what do you mean?  What actually happens?  If you mean that FORMATTED_NAME is an unsupported field for Contact, then these fields are optional.  Use `PIMList.getSupportedFields()` to figure out which fields you can read on each platform.